expo-camera 'front facing' video will not record at 2160p
When using expo-camera to record a video, the quality of 2160p is not being recorded, it downgrades to recording in 1080p. This only fails on the front facing camera. The output below shows that 2160p is indeed being shown for the front facing camera by the API through the camera.getAvailablePictureSizesAsync() method. This is on a Samsung s8 ultra (SM-X900), which has two front facing cameras both which support 2160p video recording.

This has been an issue on my end since Expo SDK 46. This problem persists across development builds as well as production builds.
My minimum reproducible example lives here.
